# Add class to an element

Tags: javascript

I try to write these code to make grid view through `CSS:( jsbin )`

```
var tables = document.getElementsByClassName('tableData');
var rows = tables[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i += 2) {
  alert(rows[i]);
  rows[i].className = "alt";
}
```

This only works with the tr elements has `class=""`. But if I want to add class to tr.

I've tried `Core.addClass` but it doesn't work.

​

Answer (score 32):

Two years later (2012/06), there is a new and shiny approach - [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList) with methods `add()`, `remove()`, `toggle()`, `contains()`.

```
rows[i].classList.add("alt");
```

Supported by

- Chrome 8+
- Firefox 3.6+
- Internet Explorer 10+
- Opera 11.50+
- Safari 5.1+

Answer (score 6):

Try `rows[i].className += " alt";`

Answer (score 2):

This will only add the class name if it doesn't already exist

```
var classToAdd = 'alt';
if (rows.className.length == 0)
{
  rows.className = classToAdd;
}
else if (rows.className.indexOf(classToAdd) < 0)
{
  rows.className += ' ' + classToAdd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a Javascript framework. It turns out that Firefox and Internet Explorer both have different approaches for adding class names.

For Firefox, I believe you have to do

```
element.setAttribute('class','<className>');
```

while in IE, you can do

```
element.className='<className>';
```

**EDIT**

It turns out that Firefox supports the `element.className` attribute. However, Internet Explorer doesn't understand `element.setAttribute('class'...)`. You have to do `element.setAttribute('className'...)` if you want to use the setAttribute function call.

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) provide an interface where you can do

```
$(element).addClass('<className>');
```

and it takes care of all the browser ambiguities. There are also [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) functions for managing and testing class attributes.

So in your scenario, you'd do:

```
var tables = document.getElementsByClassName('tableData');
var rows = tables[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(var i=1; i<rows.length; i +=2) {
    // alert(rows[i]);
    $(rows[i]).addClass("alt");
}
```

Note that you could simplify this further with more jQuery functionality.

Comment: The method setAttribute will work in IE as well.  It's standard, not specific to Firefox.  Also, className is supported by Firefox, not just IE.

Comment: @Joseph, noticed your first comment about not suggesting a specific Javascript framework. I ended up showing an example for jQuery simply because I thought the answer would benefit from one such example. Do you think it'd be better to show examples from multiple frameworks, or would it be better to leave it as it is?

Comment: @cmptrgeekken: I'd leave it as it is. Adding another framework example would just make your answer longer without any real gain in information, as most frameworks have very similar methods.

Comment: yup, jQuery is really great. But I want to learn basic first so :p
Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work even when the attribute isn't already present:

```
rows[i].setAttribute("class", "alt");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: One of us is misunderstanding the question.  I believe it's you.

Comment: @SLaks: I think that you both are a little wrong in different ways. tehMick, I think it should be `rows[i].setAttribute("class", rows[i].getAttribute("class") + " alt");`

Comment: @voyager: Yeah, I think I agree.  The snippet you gave is probably just the ticket.