# dynamically adding a css class to a div/span

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add another class to a div with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739667/add-another-class-to-a-div-with-javascript)

How can i dynamically add/remove a class to a span?

Comment: Do you mean an HTML class, a CSS ruleset or a CSS property? There is no such thing as a CSS class.

Comment: You should use something like JQuery which has addClass and removeClass methods.  Such as $('span').addClass('myClass');

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360625/add-class-to-an-element and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739667/add-another-class-to-a-div-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Set the property 'className' on the span. This will set its css class

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use jQuery to manipulate the span.

```
<span></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("span").addClass("addedClass");
$("span").removeClass("addedClass");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP to change the class.  Using some sort of link to link between different php instances.

Here would be the "button":

```
        <div class="info_tab">
            <p><?php if($_GET['state'] !='1') echo '<a href="?state=1">click to change class</a>'; else echo '<a href="page.php">click to change class back</p>' ?></p>
        </div>
```

Here would be the changing span:

```
        <span <?php if(isset($_GET['state']) && $_GET['tab'] == 1) echo 'class="state1"'; else echo 'class="state2"';?>>More information</span>
```

It's nice to have a non-javascript way for compatibility reasons for some users.